# Auto inputing into Flash website's text field

Tags: flash, selenium, automation

On flash web page, there is one text field like price field for user to input any price number, 1000, etc. And then "Okay" button on the left side.

Is there any approaches with some code to achieve the purpose: input some number into the text field and click the "Okay" button immediately by auto way.

I have tried "Selenium-flash" to do this, but not quite familiar with it.

Any ideas ?  Thanks,

Comment: can you provide a link to the page? or a sample of the html?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform only some action with the flash applet, you can use [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/). It based on image recognization to idenfity elements on the screen. But because of that you won't able to do any verification.

If you have the source code of the applet, and you want to do verification too, you can create an external interface for it and call the functions through it using javascript. Here is a quite [good article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flash_selenium.html) about it.